# Limit of convex increasing function

Tags: limits

If $f$ is strictly increasing and strictly convex (or $f'>0$ & $f''>0$), then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow∞}{f(x)}=∞$$

Is this statement true?

If this statement is true, how can I prove?

Comment: You might use the fact that convex functions lie above their tangents (i.e, for any fixed point $a$, $f(x) \geq f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$).

Answer (score 4):

Let $m=f'(0)$ and set $g(x)=mx+f(0)$.  We have $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x>0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}g(x)=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

vadim123's answer is clinical, I like it. A more traditional proof would be:

For $\forall x_0$, consider for $a>0$, $f(x_0 + a)$'s Taylor expansion at $x_0$:
$$
f(x_0+a) = f(x_0) + af'(\xi_0)
$$
for some $\xi_0 \in (x_0,x_0+a)$. Since $f''>0$ implies $f'$ is strictly increasing, we have $f'(\xi_0) > f'(x_0)= b >0$, this gives us:
$$
f(x_0+a) > f(x_0) + ab.
$$
Now consider $f(x_0 + 2a)$'s Taylor expansion at $(x_0+a)$, similar argument as above gives:
$$
f(x_0+2a) = f(x_0+a) + af'(\xi_1)> f(x_0) + ab + af'(\xi_1) >  f(x_0) + 2ab
$$
Deduction yields:
$$
f(x_0 + na)> f(x_0) + nab.
$$
Back to $f$, for $a>0$ fixed:
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_0+ na) \geq \lim_{n\to \infty} \big( f(x_0) + nab\big) = \infty.
$$